# SQL - Exclude items in sequence based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm dealing with a data set of test data where we need to exclude follow up tests from the set, but only if the first test passed in one specific area. An example is below.

`TestID          ItemID         TestDate      TestCounter     OverallResult     SafetyResult
 77466           001753        07/26/2019         1                Fail              Pass 
 77953           001753        08/06/2019         2                Pass              Pass`

In the above example, I would need to exclude TestCounter 2 because TestCounter 1 passed for safety.

I've created a reference temp table with the records with the initial pass and tried to use that as follows, but it does not appear to exclude in the way I need:

`Select TestID, ItemID, TestCounter, OverallResult, SafetyResult
From Tests t
Left Join #FirstSuccess F on t.itemid = f.itemID
Where Not (t.Testcounter = '2' and t.ItemID = f.ItemID)`

Answer (score 0):

I think `not exists` does what you want:

```
select t.*
from tests t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tests t2
                  where t2.itemID = t.itemId and
                        t2.testCounter > t.testCounter and
                        t.SafetyResult = 'Pass'
                 );
```